# Как вызвать js функцию из flask?

Tags: javascript, python, веб-программирование, flask

У меня есть сайт, написанный на Flask. В чем моя проблема: на стороне Flask я обрабатываю платежи Юкассы, а на стороне JS - работаю с данными пользователя Firebase.

Суть: после оплаты (на стороне Flask) мне нужно как-то "дернуть" функцию на стороне JS, чтобы записать данные в Firebase после оплаты.

Можно ли как-то вызвать функцию JS из Flask?

Запрос на оплату (Flask):

```
@app.route('/payment_subscription/<tariff>/', methods=['POST'])
def payment_subscription(tariff):
    return redirect(create_invoice(tariff))

def create_invoice(tariff):
    Configuration.account_id = SHOP_ID
    Configuration.secret_key = SECRET_KEY

    payment = Payment.create({
        "amount": {
            "value": TARIFF_COST_MAP[tariff],
            "currency": "RUB"
        },
        "confirmation": {
            "type": "redirect",
            "return_url": "https://www.google.com"
        },
        "capture": True,
        "description": TARIFF_DESC_MAP[tariff],
        "metadata": {
            TAG_TARIFF: tariff
        }
    }, uuid.uuid4())

    return payment.confirmation.confirmation_url


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route("/home", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            if check_if_payment_succeeded(request):
                tariff = request.json["object"]["metadata"][TAG_TARIFF]
        except:
            pass
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
```

Форма:

```
<form action="/payment_subscription/up_month_subscription" method="post">
     <input type="submit" value="Оплатить">
</form>
```

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA дополнил в вопросе код)

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA дополнил. Там обычная форма с кнопкой. При нажатии во Flask создается ссылка на оплату и сразу открывается. Когда оплата прошла, возвращается в main :)

Comment: Насколько надежным должно быть это решение в том плане, что если сразу же после выполнения запроса пользователь закроет окно в браузере и данные в firebase не успеют записаться, это ок? Нужно ли чтоб они записались, когда пользователь откроет окно заново?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA уже подумал об этой проблемке. Может есть способ как-то вызвать js функцию, даже если сайт закрыт? Я совсем новичок в web'e, может пока чего-то не понимаю :)

Comment: Если код js выполняется в браузере, то только когда страница открыта. Можно код js выполнять на сервере, тогда от браузера не будет зависеть.